# NameNode, DataNode and Secondary data with Cannot set priority error

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am just finished installation of hadoop and tired to run ./start-all.sh command in `hadoop-3.3.3/sbin` directory. I got this message

```
$ ./start-all.sh
WARNING: Attempting to start all Apache Hadoop daemons as pes1ug20cs652 in 10 seconds.
    WARNING: This is not a recommended production deployment configuration.
    WARNING: Use CTRL-C to abort.
    Starting namenodes on [localhost]
    Starting datanodes
    localhost: ERROR: Cannot set priority of datanode process 23604
    Starting secondary namenodes [Unix]
    Starting resourcemanager
    Starting nodemanagers
```

when I run jps I get only 3 processes

```
$ jps
24113 NodeManager
24460 Jps
23967 ResourceManager
```

I used the college guide to install hadoop. Here is the git [link](https://github.com/Cloud-Computing-Big-Data/UE20CS322-H1) for it (Its the file named H1_HOME_PDF)
Why aren't the remaining 3 nodes (Namenode, Datanode, Secondarynamenode) not running.
The files I changed

`/.bashrc

```
#Hadoop Path Configs
export HADOOP_HOME=/home/USER/hadoop-3.3.3
export HADOOP_INSTALL=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
export HADOOP_OPTS="Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native"
```

core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
 <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
 <value>/home/USER/tmpdata</value>
</property>
<property>
 <name>fs.default.name</name>
 <value>hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
 <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
 <value>/home/USER/dfsdata/namenode</value>
</property>
<property>
 <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
 <value>/home/USER/dfsdata/datanode</value>
</property>
<property>
 <name>dfs.replication</name>
 <value>1</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
 <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
 <value>yarn</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

yarn-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
 <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
 <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>
<property>
 <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
 <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
</property>
<property>
 <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
 <value>127.0.0.1</value>
</property>
<property>
 <name>yarn.acl.enable</name>
 <value>0</value>
</property>
<property>
 <name>yarn.nodemanager.env-whitelist</name> 
 
<value>JAVA_HOME,HADOOP_COMMON_HOME,HADOOP_HDFS_HOME,HADOOP_CONF_DIR,CLA
SSPATH_PERPEND_DISTCACHE,HADOOP_YARN_HOME,HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Why are the 3 nodes not working?

Comment: Seems fine, but you should use `start-dfs` or individual start daemon commands rather than start-all. Then there will be more complete log output for each process that you can debug. Also, that command won't start every node on its own

Comment: @OneCricketeer I tried doing just start-dfs, But it still gives me  **Error:Cannot set priority of datanode process 3769**

Comment: Sure, but there are other logs files written to disk (in the current folder, or logs subfolder) that have more information.